# Computer Vision version 6.0.0 ReadInStreamAsync method returns "Operation returned invalid status code 'Not Found'"

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, computer-vision, containers

Im new to computer vision, we have set up computer vision OCR container with image tag: docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/vision/read:3.2-preview.1 and specified:

1)billing endpoint
2)eula -> Accept
3)api key

Container is up and running and is listening to port 5000.

service endpoint '/ready' returns:
{"service": "Computervisionread", "ready":"ready", "message":"Api is ready"}.

so whenever we call any microsoft visionclient(version 6.0.0) methods for example:
'ReadInStreamAsync' method returns "Operation returned invalid status code 'Not Found'" error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

QA: How could we know which version of SDK supports which version of container image?

Comment: Are you using https (secure) or http?  See : https://github.com/microsoft/containerregistry/blob/master/client-firewall-rules.md

Comment: What is the endpoint you are using ?